# How can I use mongodb to hold my application files running on node.js instead of having them on filesystem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When using node.js together with ExpressJS I always have to place my application logic on the filesystem. Is there a way to put them in MongoDB for example? Should I use some other middleware instead of ExpressJS, or can it somehow be done with ExpressJS?

I have tried looking for middleware that might do node.js routing to a database, but with no result.